# ModelBuilder appends .shp to output file after running

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4, raster-to-point

I'm running model that processes line features into a raster, and I'm using a `raster to point` tool to further sieve the result.

When the model hasn't run yet, these are the tool parameters:
[image]

As you can see, the result is as a GDB feature class, and everything work perfectly.

Yet after running the tool once, the output now has a .shp appended to it, and since it's written in a gdb, it obviously throws an error.

[image]

Is there a way to override this or is it a bug?

This is the only tool that does so in a model with more than 150 tools.

Comment: The %ver% is not inserting a \ ?

Comment: @Björn No, its a variable that I add to all the outputs to track the versioning, it's a project still in work.

Comment: A roundabout solution could be to allow it to create a temporary shapefile and then copy features to a feature class in your geodatabase

Comment: What would %ver% typically hold? May be it is an invalid character like a space so the tool is defaulting to a shapefile which would allow such characters?

Comment: @Hornbydd a two digit number

Comment: To get to the bottom of this one I think you will need to try and create a smaller test model from the bits of this one that you are suspicious of, and see if you can reproduce the same symptom there  Otherwise, your question may only attract answers that say they have seem similar symptoms.

Comment: @PolyGeo I still haven't tried reproducing the error exactly, yet other models immigrated to 10.4 without a problem. I'll get to it in the near future, but I'd like this question to remain open for the chance that someone figured/will figure it out.

Comment: Now that it has an answer with an upvote it will stay off the Unanswered list, and thus be less prone to closure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem with a model I created in 10.3.1. My model iterates through a bunch of tile boundary feature classes residing in a file GDB and uses each tile as an extent to contour a DEM.  In 10.4 the contour tool appends a .shp to the end of my feature class name and throws an error.  It doesn't happen in 10.3.1, so I'm guessing its a pesky bug.